# Can spontaneous fluctuations cause instantaneous non-equilibrium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

The fluctuation-dissipation theorem says that the linear response of a given system to an external perturbation is expressed as the fluctuation properties of the system in thermal equilibrium.

Does this mean that the spontaneous fluctuations cause instantaneous non-equilibrium, and the long-time average is the equilibrium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The theorem also quantifies how far from equilibrium the system is likely to fluctuate and how quickly it is expected to return to equilibrium.

Details are described in Evans and Searles “The Fluctuation Theorem”. Advances in Physics. 2002. 51(7): 1529-85. https://doi.org/10.1080/00018730210155133

Comment: Thanks a lot,  could you please show me a reference? I'd like to go through it in detail.

Comment: I would suggest https://doi.org/10.1080/00018730210155133 and will add it to the answer